# Ionic Android app rejected in play store - Location permission

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, geolocation, android-permissions

My app got rejected from play store mentioning the below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyG7i.png)

But we have mentioned the same the app and also added a video of the same while submitting for review. But got rejected again.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDZOJ.jpg)

We have already tried giving more description why we are accessing the location and added a youtube url of the video while submitting the app.
But still it got rejected.

Please can someone help us with this

Comment: you have to write the description inside the <location-usage> which lies in the info-plist.xml ... our app got rejected 38 times but apple never even bothered to give a clear reply ...they never do... so we eventually figured out ourselves